# Erro na conversão ABS PHP?

Tags: php

Tenho a seguinte rotina:

```
    $saldisp = -13.02; // Resultado de uma operação matemática
    $valorpagar = "13,02"; // Coloquei o valor real que vem do Edit

    $saldodisp = (float) abs($saldisp);

    $valorpagar = (float) $valorpagar;

    if ($valorpagar < 10) {
        fValida(__LINE__, "", "", "O valor mínimo para pagamento é de R$ 10,00");
    } else {
        if ($saldodisp < $valorpagar) { // Ele entra aqui?
            fValida(__LINE__, "", "", "Valor máximo para pagamento é de R$ " . ($saldodisp));
        }
    }
```

Ele esta entrando no segundo IF, mas no IF os valores são exatamente iguais 13,02

A unica coisa que difere é antes do IF é que o saldodisp é negativo (-13,02) e o valor que vem do Edit é positivo (13,02)

Mas estou convertendo o negativo com o abs()

O que pode estar faltando ainda?

obs: Colocando um debug no if o valor de saldisp é 13,02 e do Edit é 13,02

Não consigo encontrar onde esta o erro.

Poderíamos dizer que é erro de conversão quando há N casas decimais, mas aí o debug me mostraria essas casas, e eu não estou fazendo nenhuma divisão ou multiplicação, simplesmente estou pegando o valor do banco convertendo com abs e comparando com o valor que vem do edit

Comment: Queira [edit] e converter seu código em um [mcve] para que possamos testar e ajudar (fazendo de forma a podermos executar o trecho conferindo o problema sem depender do seu DB, para validação das afirmações passadas).

Comment: Confesso que eu não sabia o resultado literal de (float) 13.02, o que está ocorrendo é que o (float) está convertendo na moeda local 13,02 e pelo que parece o php está comparando duas strings, ao formatar os valores de volta para 13.02 (substituindo ponto por virgula) ele faz a comparação correta no if.

Comment: Melhorou seu edit, só que pra ser um MCVE é importante que ele cause o mesmo problema que o código original, tem que checar se o que veio do DB é string ou se é numero (exemplo: `$saldisp = '-13,02';`) - mas igualzinho vem do db

Comment: Esqueci do sinal de menos, ele vem do banco assim -13.02 e do Edit ele vem 13.02, mas ao usar o (float) na frente ele converte os valores para 13,02 (com virgula) isso acaba dando problema no if que compra strings e não floats, eu usei o (float) porque no banco há valores com mais de 2 casas decimais, mas não espera esse tipo de conversão, achei que o php leria como decimal.

Comment: Você precisa dizer que tipo de valor tem no seu banco de dados. Seria float mesmo? Decimal? String? Float é uma coisa complicada, e não é recomendado para lidar com valores monetários, por problemas de precisão. Por exemplo, às vezes 2 valores parecem idênticos mas não são, especialmente se um deles for resultado de alguma operação matemática. Exemplo: https://ideone.com/EisV9g

Comment: Marcelo, para clarificar, esse código da pergunta está dando o mesmo erro? (Nao tenho como testar agora, tou no expediente). Se não está dando o erro, precisa ver o que tem diferente do DB. Se está, aí resolveu a pergunta e está adequada para uma resposta (que pode provavelmente ser uma que já tem no site sobre comparação de float, o mesmo problema que o @bfavaretto mencionou).

Comment: No meu banco está como decimal (12,4) que pode ser negativo e no exemplo que passei o numero retornado do banco é exatamente (-13.02), mas o problema foi usar a função (float) para trabalhar números com mais de 2 casas decimais e ter certeza de que strings (13,02) seriam convertidas em decimal (13,02), pois ele transforma na moeda local com os devidos separadores e isso causa problema na comparação. O uso do (float) foi precaução, mas me trouxe um problema, já resolvi a questão. Depois vou postar.

Comment: Bacco, realmente o exemplo do bfavaretto está de acordo... o resultado vem de uma operação e isso esta causando o problema, no exemplo acima eu quis simplificar, mas não testei... fazendo o teste o exemplo acima não da erro, obrigado por mais essa. @bfavaretto coloque como resposta pra eu aceitar.

Comment: Marcelo, achei melhor marcar como duplicata (e coloquei 4 referências), pois tem muitas outras perguntas sobre o assunto aqui. Como eu não sei exatamente a origem da divergência no seu caso específico, fica complicado responder.